# Will proof of work still be required after coordicide?

Tags: iota-network

Will proof of work used for anything after Coordicide goes live?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PoW will still be used for [spam protection and rate control](https://coordicide.iota.org/module3). The adaptive difficulty will depend on the current throughput of the network and the reputation of the node (ie. mana).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it wont anymore. In the abstract of https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.07778 it says,

> In this work, we consider a novel IoT-friendly DLT architecture based on directed acyclic graphs, rather than a blockchain, and with
> a reputation system in the place of Proof of Work (PoW).

Similarly [in their specification](https://github.com/iotaledger/IOTA-2.0-Research-Specifications/blob/main/4.6%20Congestion%20Control.md), they mention for the congestion control a,

> A TCP-inspired algorithm for decentralized rate setting to efficiently utilize the available bandwidth while preventing large delays.

With no mention of POW. As you probably remember from [their blog post](https://blog.iota.org/explaining-the-iota-congestion-control-algorithm/#rate-control) in march,

> We use an adaptive PoW as a rate control mechanism. For honest nodes, the PoW difficulty is relatively low. But if a node begins to spam, the difficulty exponentially increases, physically preventing them from issuing more messages.

Without any official comment, I am concluding that they intend to remove POW or adaptive POW in favor of simply just using Mana as a rate controller. Making it exponentially harder to send transactions in adaptive POW is essentially the same thing as just blocking transactions; it makes sense just to remove it.